# How to Configure Multiple Ldap Connection- WSO2 Indentity Server

Tags: ldap, wso2, wso2-identity-server

I have multiple tenants. Some tenant has single ldap server and some are using multiple so I want to configure multiple ldap connection using some user interface in WSO2 Identity Server. Please suggest what is the best way?

Answer (score 0):

Configuring multiple user stores can be done and a detailed guide line of configuring ldap user store can be found in [this blog post](http://sureshatt.blogspot.com/2012/07/how-to-connect-wso2-api-manager-to.html).

Configuring tenant specific user stores ain't support for the current versions of Identity Server but it is an one of new features of Identity Server 4.5.0 which will be released in July 2013.

Thanks,